# dart null-safe list declaration

Tags: list, dart, dart-null-safety

I wanted to use this [pin code field generator](https://github.com/prestigegodson/pin-entry-text-field/blob/master/pin_entry_text_field/lib/pin_entry_text_field.dart), but parts of it are deprecated.

```
_pin = List<String>(widget.fields);
_focusNodes = List<FocusNode>(widget.fields);
_textControllers = List<TextEditingController>(widget.fields);
```

(widget.fields is an integer)
These lines tell me `'List' is deprecated.` I tried to convert the first one to List.filled(not sure it's correct though), but couldn't figure out the others.

```
 List<String> _pin;
List<FocusNode> _focusNodes;
  List<TextEditingController> _textControllers;
_pin = List<String>.filled(widget.fields, '');
```

I read through the documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.filled.html), but it's not clear enough for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer while looking for something else, so I should be using list.generate instead of list.filled. Please [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67949610/4335303) if you are interested.